# I need to eliminate special characters using regex

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

My application has support for multilingual languages; but below is my code which allows only english charcters

```
Regex.Match(inputstr, "[^a-z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I need to eliminate that input string has any of the special characters and it should allow other language normal characters(like Japanese kanji characters)

Below is my code doesn't work for any language please let me know where i made a mistake

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(txtInput.Text.Trim(), @"[^+^-^.^,^!^@^#^$^%^^^&^*^(^)^;^|^<^>^'^/^_^=^}^{^?^:^~^`^]"))
{
 //show error
}
else
{
//valid characters
}
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Is this your suggestion? Please let me know Regex.IsMatch(txtInput.Text.Trim(), @"[^+^-^.^,^!^@^#^$^%^^^&^*^(^)^;^|^<^>^'^/^_^=^}^{^?^:^~^`^]+")

Comment: if you want to match one or more non word characters then you could simply use `[\W_]+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj perfect your code works! but also it excludes space characters :( i need to allow space between words HOW?

Comment: try this `(?:[^\w ]+|_+)`. Let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: Awesome!! works for me!!! also i tried [^\w\s]+ it is working as expected!!! which one is good to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match special  characters except the spaces.

```
(?:[^\w ]+|_+)
```

Then trim out the matched characters using Trim function.

Comment: The underscore is contained in \w so not sure why you would add that as an alternative match with `|`.

Comment: @funkwurm he wants to match special charcters ..ie, `_` included.. While in the char class `[^\w ]`, this won't match the underscore symbol.

Comment: ah, it's a negative character class, my bad.